# Angular distribution of lines passing through two squares.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, trigonometry, probability-distributions, physics

Let's say I've got two squares with side length $d$ that are held parallel at a distance $m$ apart.

Suppose that particles are randomly falling from above in such a way that the polar angle $\varphi$ of the trajectory of the particles has a probability distribution proportional to $\operatorname{cos}^2(\varphi)$, while the azimuthal angle is uniformly distributed.

A particle is *admissible* if it passes through *both* squares.

[image: figure: admissible particles]

> Can we find a closed form expression for the probability distribution of the polar angle of admissible particles?  (or at least a good numerical solution?)

---

**My attempt at a stronger formulation:**

First, let's normalize the problem by letting $\alpha=m/d$ and assuming each square has unit side length.  We may assume that the point at which the particle passes through Panel $1$ (the upper panel) is uniformly distributed, that is, there are a uniformly distributed variables $X_1$ and $Y_1$, each between $0$ and $1$, and the point of contact on the plane of panel $1$ is $$\mathfrak{X}_1=\left(\begin{array}{c}X_1\\Y_1\\ \alpha\end{array}\right).$$  In order to be admissible, a particle must pass through Panel $1$, and we are only interested in admissible particles, so this is our universe of particles.

Let's find the point of contact $\mathfrak{X}_2$ on the plane of Panel $2$ (the lower panel).  We need $$\left(\begin{array}{c}X_1+t\operatorname{sin}(\varphi)\operatorname{cos}(\theta)\\ Y_1+t\operatorname{sin}(\varphi)\operatorname{sin}(\theta)\\ \alpha+t\operatorname{cos}(\varphi)\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}X_2\\Y_2\\0\end{array}\right)$$
so $t=-\alpha\operatorname{sec}(\varphi)$, from which we have $$\mathfrak{X}_2=\left(\begin{array}{c}X_1-\alpha\operatorname{tan}(\varphi)\operatorname{cos}(\theta)\\Y_1-\alpha\operatorname{tan}(\varphi)\operatorname{sin}(\theta)\\0\end{array}\right).$$
So, the question is, what is the probability distribution of $\varphi$ for the lines satisfying
$$\begin{array}{rcl}0 \leq& X_1-\alpha\operatorname{tan}(\varphi)\operatorname{cos}(\theta) &\leq  1 \\
0 \leq& Y_1-\alpha\operatorname{tan}(\varphi)\operatorname{sin}(\theta) &\leq 1 \end{array}
$$
given that $$\begin{array}{rl}X_1 \text{ and }Y_1& \text{are uniformly distributed from }0\text{ to }1 \\ \theta &\text{is uniformly distributed from }0\text{ to }2\pi \\ \varphi & \text{has probability distribution }\frac{4}{\pi}\operatorname{cos}^2\varphi\text{ from }\frac{\pi}{2}\text{ to }\pi\end{array}$$
?

---

**EDIT 2:**

So I ran a simulation, yielding the following histogram (displayed below with $3$ different bin widths).  I haven't fit a curve to this yet, but maybe it will give us a hint.  Here $\alpha$ is about $6$.

[image: dem chartz]

Comment: The polar angle $\varphi$ is with respect the vertical, right (0=vertical ray)?

Comment: @leonbloy Yep, or $\pi$.  (I chose $\varphi$ to be from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ because I set the problem up with the particle going down, but one could as easily make it $0$ to $\pi/2$.)

Comment: I'm going to assume this is a nuclear physics (or similar) related question. In that case, I don't think there's anything wrong with using the simulated distribution,since yo'll probably end up with a numerical integral as it is.

Comment: @nbubis Actually it comes from experimental particle physics.  (I'm romancing a Cherenkov detector.)  The simulation will be okay if necessary but it'd be neat to see an exact-ish solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d=\alpha \tan (\varphi) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$ be the distance (projected over the $z$ axis) between the point points at which the ray intersect the square planes. (Disregard for now the restriction that the ray passes through the squares).

Then, the probability density of $d$ can obtained, by the usual transformation of variables, from the density of $\varphi$, as

$$P(d) \propto \frac{1}{(\alpha^2 +d^2)^2} \,\, (d\ge 0)$$

Now, instead of considering just one pair of unit squares, let's imagine that the planes are tiled by a grid of such squares, and let $E$ be the event that the rays passes through a pair or aligned squares. Then, we are insterested in computing

$$P(d|E) = \frac{P(E|d) P(d)}{P(E)}$$

The denominator is just a normalization constant, so we are left with computing $P(E|d)$
Because the azimuthal angle is uniform, fixing $d$ means considering a circle of that radius and random (uniform) center, with uniform distribution along its circumference. We want to compute the probability that a point of that circle falls inside the same square as its center. Which is the same of computing **the fraction of its circumference that falls inside the unit square** (conditioned on the center coordinates, and integrated uniformly over the square). 
Because of symmetry, it's enough to consider the west-south quarter of circle; lets compute the fraction of this quarter-of circumference that falls **outside** the unit square. We have two ranges of interest: for $0\le d<1$ we have to consider 5 zones, and for $1\le d <\sqrt{2}$ we have 2 zones.

[image]

Lets deal with $0\le d<1$, where $P(E|d) = 1 - (I_A+2 I_{Bx} +I_C+ I_D)$. When the center of the circle falls in zone A, : the quater of circumference fall all inside the square (so $I_A=0$). At zone D, it falls all outside, the fraction is 1, which integrated over the region gives a contribution of $I_D=\pi d^2 /4$

Zone C is more complex:

[image]

The relevant fraction is the ratio of the red arcs over $\pi/2$, which must be integrated over the zone. This is

$$ \frac{2}{\pi} \int_C acos(x/d)+acos(y/d) dx dy = \frac{4 d^2}{\pi} \int_0^1(1-\sqrt{1-t^2}) acos(t) \, dt = \frac{d^2(12-\pi^2)}{4 \pi}$$

Similarly:

$$I_{BX}= I_{BY}= \frac{2}{\pi} \int_d^1 \int_0^d acos(y/d) dy dx = \frac{2}{\pi} (1-d) d $$

So $$P(E|d) = g_1(d) \triangleq 1 - (I_A+2 I_{Bx} +I_C+ I_D) = 1 + \frac{d^2-4d}{\pi}$$.

(The range $1 < d < \sqrt{2}$, though we have less zones, it's more complicated [*] )

From that, we get the form of $P(\varphi,E)$ in the range $0\le d\le 1$ , or $0 \le \varphi \le atan (1/\alpha)$ :

$$P(\varphi|E) \propto \cos^2  \varphi \, (\pi - 4 \alpha \tan \varphi +  \alpha^2 \tan^2 \varphi) = (\pi -\alpha^2) \cos^2  \varphi - 2 \alpha \cos(2 \varphi) +  \alpha^2  $$

This (unless errors) is exact in that range, but to get the proportionality factor one would need to consider also the remaining (small) tail, on  $1 < d < \sqrt{2}$.

[*] In the "tail zone", $P(E|d) = 1 - (I_E+I_{F} )$ with

$$ I_E = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_E acos(x/d) dy dx = \frac{4}{\pi} \int_{\sqrt{d^2-1}}^1 (1-\sqrt{d^2-x^2}) acos(x/d) dx$$

$$ I_F =  \int_F 1 dy dx = \sqrt{d^2-1} + \int_{\sqrt{d^2-1}}^1 \sqrt{d^2-x^2}) dx$$

$$P(E|d)= g_2(d) \triangleq \frac{1}{2 \pi}\left[ -2\,{d}^{2}\,{\mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{\sqrt{{d}^{2}-1}}{d}\right) }^{2}+\left( \pi \,{d}^{2}-4\,{d}^{2}\,\mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{\sqrt{{d}^{2}-1}}{d}\right) \right) \,\mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{\sqrt{{d}^{2}-1}}{d}\right) +\sqrt{{d}^{2}-1}\,\left( 4\,\mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{\sqrt{{d}^{2}-1}}{d}\right) +4\,\mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{1}{d}\right) -2\,\pi +8\right) +\left( 2\,{\mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{1}{d}\right) }^{2}+\left( 4\,\mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{1}{d}\right) -\pi \right) \,\mathrm{asin}\left( \frac{1}{d}\right) -2\right) \,{d}^{2}-8\,\mathrm{acos}\left( \frac{1}{d}\right) +2\,\pi -4 \right]$$

(Sorry, Maxima cannot simplify this further). 
The integrals of $P(E|d)$ over the two regions are $1-5/(3 \pi) = 0.469483523$ and
$0.00371748$ respectively. Here's a graph of  $P(E|d)$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Bayes' theorem:
$$ P(\phi\mid\text{admissible}) = \frac{P(\text{admissible}|\phi)P(\phi)}{P(\text{admissible})}. $$

Unless I am misreading your question (what do you do about rays that are parallel to an admissible ray? I am assuming here they are admissible, so only the direction or a ray matters), a ray parametrized by
$$ (t \sin\phi \cos\theta, t \sin\phi \sin\theta, t \cos\phi), \qquad t\in\mathbb{R}, \quad 0\leq\phi\leq\frac\pi2, \qquad 0\leq\theta\leq2\pi $$
is admissible if at the point $m = z(t) = t\cos\phi$, we have
$$ |t\sin\phi\cos\theta| \leq d, \quad\text{and}\quad |t\sin\phi\sin\theta| \leq d, $$
because if it passes through the two squares, the most it can move at most $d$ in either $x$- or $y$-direction as it moves a distance $m$ in $z$-direction. This condition is equivalent to
$$ |\tan\phi\cos\theta| \leq d/m, \qquad |\tan\phi\sin\theta| \leq d/m = \alpha, $$
which is equivalent to
$$ |\tan\phi|^2 \leq 2\alpha^2 = (\tan\phi_0)^2, \qquad \max(|\cos\theta|,|\sin\theta|) \leq \frac{\alpha}{|\tan\phi|}. $$

Finally, $ P(\phi) = \frac{4}{\pi}\cos^2\phi$, and, setting $\beta=\alpha/|\tan\phi|$, $P(\text{admissible}) = \text{const}$, and
$$ P(\text{admissible}|\phi) = [\phi\leq\phi_0] P\left( \max(|\cos\theta|,|\sin\theta|) \leq \beta \right)
\\ = [\phi\leq\phi_0] 4 P(\theta\geq\arccos\beta, \theta\leq\arcsin\beta\mid0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2)
\\ = [\phi\leq\phi_0]([\beta\geq1] + \frac{2}{\pi}(\arcsin\beta-\arccos\beta)[\beta\leq1]). $$

Putting things together,
$$ P(\phi\mid\text{admissible}) \propto \cos^2\phi \times [\phi\leq\phi_0]([\beta\geq1]+\frac{2}{\pi}[\beta\leq1](\arcsin\beta-\arccos\beta)). $$
The constant of proportionality is found by integrating the rhs over $0\leq\phi\leq\frac\pi2$ and setting it to $1$, but probably doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: I've edited my question attempting to answer your question on parallel rays.

Comment: My answer is no longer applicable.

Comment: Thanks anyhow for the work so far. It really helped me with my own work towards the problem.